# Creating a drop down for quantity selector in shopify website

Tags: javascript, performance, shopify

Hi I have created a dropdown as a quantity selector in my Shopify website.

```html
<select name="quantity" id="quantity">
         {% for i in (1..10) %}
                  <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
          {% endfor %}         
</select>
```

Here is my code for the quantity selector. and it is working fine. So I have question . is it possible to reflect the total number of quantity in my stock. right now I am using 1..10. that is why it is showing 1 to 10 in my drop-down

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you can.

If your product doesn't have any options you can use the `product.first_available_variant.inventory_quantity` for example:

```
<select name="quantity" id="quantity">
         {% for i in (1..product.first_available_variant.inventory_quantity) %}
                  <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
          {% endfor %}         
</select>
```

But if you have options you will need to rely on Javascript to generate the select.

In this case you can generate a Javascript object with all the variants and their invetory_quantity:

```
<script>
    var qtyVaraints = {
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {{variant.id}}: {{variant.inventory_quantity}}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    }
</script>
```

And based on the selected variant you will target the object `qtyVaraints[VARIANT_ID]` and generate new options for the select based on the return number from the above object.